# Check if Vehicle is available in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table:

```
BookingID userID VehicleId FromDate   ToDate     Comments TotalPrice Status 
9         14     1015      2021-08-03 2021-08-08          258        0      
10        14     1015      2021-08-10 2021-08-12          129        0     
11        14     1015      2021-08-13 2021-08-14          129        0      
12        14     1015      2021-08-18 2021-08-23          129        0
```

And this PHP function:

```
function isBooked($VehicleID, $fromDate, $toDate) {
   $sql = "SELECT BookingID, VehicleID, FromDate, ToDate FROM tbl_bookings WHERE VehicleID = $VehicleID";

   $con = new Database_Connector();
   $result = $con->read_records($sql);
   $flag = 0;
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) && $flag == 0)
   {
      $bFromDate = $row['FromDate'];
      $bToDate = $row['ToDate'];

      if (($fromDate >= $bFromDate) && ($toDate <= $bToDate)){
         $flag = 1;
      }
   }
      if ($flag==1) {
         echo "Not available";
      } else { echo "is Available"; }
}
```

What I need is on the given dates $fromDate and $toDate to check if they are records in the booking table on that specific date range.

Idealy given:

- fromDate: 2021-08-04, $toDate: 2021-08-05 should echo "Not available"
- fromDate: 2021-08-04, $toDate: 2021-08-12 should echo "Not available"
- fromDate: 2021-08-15, $toDate: 2021-08-17 should echo "Available"
- fromDate: 2021-08-15, $toDate: 2021-08-29 should echo "Not available"

My code from what I can understand checks only the set of dates of each row. Hence I receive the wrong results. Anyone can propose a better solution? I'm open to totally different approaches.

UPDATE:

```
function isBooked($VehicleID, $fromDate, $toDate) {

    $sql= "SELECT CASE WHEN y.BookingID IS NOT NULL AND VehicleID=$VehicleID THEN '0' ELSE '1' END availability
           FROM (SELECT 1)x LEFT JOIN tbl_bookings y ON FromDate <= '$toDate' AND ToDate > '$fromDate'";
           echo $sql;
    $con = new Database_Connector();
    $result = $con->read_records($sql);
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         $variable = $row['availability'];
      }
    if ($variable == 0) {
      return 0;
    }elseif ($variable == 1) {
       return 1;
    }else {
      return "error";
    }
}

function addBooking ($VehicleID, $fromDate, $toDate, $message, $userID) {
   $status = 0;
   $days = (round ((strtotime($toDate) - strtotime($fromDate)) / (60 * 60 *24)))+1;
   $vPrice = getVehiclePrice($VehicleID);
   $TotalPrice = $vPrice * $days;
   $sql= "INSERT INTO tbl_bookings(BookingID, userID, VehicleId, FromDate, ToDate, Comments, TotalPrice, Status, PostingDate, LastUpdationDate) VALUES (DEFAULT, '$userID', '$VehicleID', '$fromDate', '$toDate', '$message', '$TotalPrice', '$status', DEFAULT, DEFAULT)";
    $con = new Database_Connector();
    $result = $con->execute_query($sql);
    if($result != FALSE){
        return "Booking submited successful";
    }else{
        return "Something went wrong. Please try again";
    }
}

function generateBookings($x) {
   $i=1;
   while ($i <= $x) {
      $days = mt_rand(1, 10);
      $daysText = '+ '. $days. ' days';
      $min_date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
      $max_date = strtotime(date('2021-12-30'));
      $rand_start_date = date('Y-m-d', rand($min_date, $max_date));
      $rand_end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rand_start_date. $daysText));

      $rand_VehicleID = mt_rand(1001, 1020);
      $rand_UserID = mt_rand(17, 25);
      $message = "Lorem Ipsum Dollor";

      if (isBooked($rand_VehicleID, $rand_start_date, $rand_end_date) == 1 ) {
         addBooking ($rand_VehicleID, $rand_start_date, $rand_end_date, $message, $rand_UserID);
         $i = $i+1;
      }
   }
}
```

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67c994/1/0

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Also, be warned that your queries are widely open for SQL injection

Comment: Thanks for the injection warning. This is something Im going to fix once the code is working. Im using @coyeb60297 solution to avoid overlaping date range. On the UPDATE section I have 3 functions that generate random data and insert them to the DB. I need to avoid dates overlaping for each Vehicle ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS OscarCy;

CREATE TABLE OscarCy
(BookingID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,FromDate  DATE NOT NULL
,ToDate DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO OscarCy VALUES
( 9,'2021-08-03','2021-08-08'),
(10,'2021-08-10','2021-08-12'),
(11,'2021-08-13','2021-08-14'),
(12,'2021-08-18','2021-08-23');
```

...

```
SET @range_start = '2021-08-15';
SET @range_end = '2021-08-29';


SELECT CASE WHEN y.bookingid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Not Available' ELSE 'Available' END availability
 FROM (SELECT 1)x
 LEFT 
 JOIN OscarCy y
   ON fromdate <= @range_end
  AND todate > @range_start;

+---------------+
| availability  |
+---------------+
| Not Available |
+---------------+

SET @range_start = '2021-08-15';
SET @range_end = '2021-08-17';

SELECT CASE WHEN y.bookingid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Not Available' ELSE 'Available' END availability
 FROM (SELECT 1)x
 LEFT 
 JOIN OscarCy y
   ON fromdate <= @range_end
  AND todate > @range_start;

+--------------+
| availability |
+--------------+
| Available    |
+--------------+
```

Note that the only other answer thus far provided appears to use an incorrect comparison for overlaps. I'd comment, but I don't have the rep.

EDIT: With reference to your comment, I don't understand it. Here's the subset of data for VehicleId 1020, and where 'x' represents bookings that overlap with the give date range...

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+------------+------+
| BookingID | userID | VehicleId | FromDate   | ToDate     | Comments           | TotalPrice | x    |
+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+------------+------+
|       296 | 22     |      1020 | 2021-08-11 | 2021-08-12 | Lorem Ipsum Dollor | 3000       |    0 |
|       313 | 24     |      1020 | 2021-08-31 | 2021-09-08 | Lorem Ipsum Dollor | 13500      |    0 |
|       326 | 17     |      1020 | 2021-11-12 | 2021-11-22 | Lorem Ipsum Dollor | 16500      |    1 |
|       335 | 21     |      1020 | 2021-09-20 | 2021-09-29 | Lorem Ipsum Dollor | 15000      |    0 |
+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+------------+------+
```

I can't see that there are any other 'overlaps' here.

Comment: That looks interesting. I would love a brief description of your logic!

Comment: That's a good answer; dependant upon the logic following the database call, a case statement is a very clean way of doing it

Comment: @OscarCy The rule for overlaps is as follows: Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and ends after Event B starts. That's all the logic there is!

Comment: @WillJones Good, and yet, tragically, not worthy of an upvote :-(

Comment: Hi @coyeb60297. I have updated the initial post with a few functions that generate random bookings, check the dates using your idea and then add them to the DB. Unfortunatly for some reason I do get invalid data in DB. the dates actually are overlap on each row. If you have the will can you have a look?

Comment: @OscarCy See Edit above.

Comment: Hi @coyeb60297 check this link here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67c994/1
Maybe I messed it up with the VehicleID?

Comment: @OscarCy Incidentally, I think your business logic is flawed, as it allows for the creation of a race condition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Consider whether the idbooking function is even necessary, or whether the whole thing can be bound up within a transaction (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-transactional-statements.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a potential SQL injection vulnerability in your code:

```
//THIS IS DANGEROUS

$sql = "SELECT BookingID, VehicleID, FromDate, ToDate FROM tbl_bookings WHERE VehicleID = $VehicleID";
$con = new Database_Connector();
$result = $con->read_records($sql);

//DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS INSTEAD

$sql = "SELECT BookingID, VehicleID, FromDate, ToDate FROM tbl_bookings WHERE VehicleID = :vehicleID";
$con = new Database_Connector();
$result = $con->read_records($sql, ['vehicleID' => $VehicleID]);
```

If `$VehicleID` ends up as something like `1; DROP TABLE tbl_bookings;--`, you could find yourself having a really, really bad day.
You should be parameterising your queries to protect against these kinds of (unfortunately exceedingly common) attacks.

To answer your actual question, I'd probably offload the date checking to the database, using something like this:

```
function isBooked($VehicleID, $fromDate, $toDate) {
    $sql = "SELECT BookingID, VehicleID, FromDate, ToDate FROM tbl_bookings WHERE VehicleID = :VehicleID and (FromDate >= :FromDate and ToDate <= :ToDate";
    $con = new Database_Connector();
    $results = $con->read_records($sql, ['VehicleID' => $VehicleID, 'FromDate' => $fromDate, 'ToDate' => $toDate]);
    if (empty($results)) {
        echo "Available";
    } else {
        echo "Not Available";
    }
}
```

I'm unsure what type `$con->read_records` returns, so I don't know if an `empty()` check would work. You may have to use `$results->rowCount() === 0` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the injection avoidance tip, I'll adopt it.
The results though still not accurate with your solution, $result is always empty. Could you please give me a brief explanation on how sql does the dates comparison. I might be able to correct it. Thansk for your time and effort.

Comment: It depends on how your dates are stored in mysql, but it does a basic comparison similar to how you're trying to do it in PHP. If they're stored as varchar fields, this won't work. If you store them as date/datetime fields, it will because internally, mysql converts them to a format that can be used to do comparisons. If they're stored as timestamp, they're stored as unix epochs.

Comment: Hi @Will Jones, I've tried your proposal to avoid sql injections but, for some reason it gives me the error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given. It might not return any results cause probably the sql statement is broken due to the variable not passing preperly I guess.

Comment: @OscarCy without seeing the method definition for read_records, I wouldn't be able to shed any more light unfortunately. If the result is a boolean, it's probably false and therefore there's something broken somewhere.